# Components needed for VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, adsl, mac-mini, osx-server

We eventually got our Mac Mini Server. We now want to set up a small Remote Access VPN using this Mac Mini Server.

Firstly we are not sure of the components needed additionally to the server to setup this VPN. We currently have the following:

- 1 Mac Mini Server
- 1 Firewall Router (Billion 802.11g ADSL2+ router with VPN capabilities [it says so on the box])
- 4Mbps ADSL connection (which should have VPN capability enabled by the service provider, or so we heard)

We are not sure what else needs to be included to enable our small VPN. Any advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now all you need is the VPN software itself.  Not a Mac guy myself, but there may be an app in the Mac that can be used.  Otherwise, [try this.](http://vlandham.wordpress.com/2006/09/26/openvpn-server-on-mac/) I really like OpenVPN, and I use it to connect to my work and from work to connect my home system, both of which are completely different server setups.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, my post might sound like our ADSL connection has VPN enabled on it, but we have not contacted our ISP to do so. I assume it is a required step in the whole process or can it be left out?

Comment: Good question.  I believe ISPs don't put restrictions on VPNs.  You just need to make sure you allow the traffic through your firewall.